# Recyclerview/cardview replace default popUp title item not working kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a `recyclerview` using `cardview`. Every cardview with its own `popUp Menu`. It works well when using the default menu `title`

**menu.xml**

```
  <item android:id="@id+/add_word" android:title="Add new word" />
```

Now I want to replace the default `title` by the one generates dynamically in the recyclerview.

```
val wordType = "Verb"//variable
holder.itemView.buttomMenu.setOnClickListener{ view ->

        val popUpMenu = PopupMenu(context,view)
        popUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { it ->
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.add_word -> {  

                 it.title = "Add " + wordType

                    Toast.makeText(context,"Add new Clicked " + wordType,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
                               }
                            }
                   true
                    }
        popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.home_menu_item_menu)
        popUpMenu.show()

                true
                   }
```

This code works correctly, but the problem is that the `popUp Menu Item` changes its `title` only when I click on it.

I want it to change the `title` without having clicking on it. just before. make a direct replace for `Add new word` to `Add Verb`, in this case

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sequence, first inflate the view of the popup `popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.home_menu_item_menu)`
and then set the dynamic message in the title, the call
`popUpMenu.show()` method.

Comment: and how do I set the dynamic messge in the title, this is my question..Itried to put `popUpMenu.view.id.add_word.title = wordType` after the inflate menu, but throws red errors